# What is the replacement for replaceRange(); in JTextArea, for JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am currently updating my code for an old applet and I am converting from awt to swing. I want to take advantage of more customization via JTextPane than the old TextArea in awt.

```
textArea.selectAll();
textArea.replaceRange("", textArea.getSelectionStart(),
textArea.getSelectionEnd());
```

How do I make that compliant with a JTextPane? Here is the error I am getting from running the  java *.java command.

```
chatPne.java:138: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method replaceRange(java.lang.String,int,int)
location: class javax.swing.JTextPane
                                textArea.replaceRange("", textArea.getSelectionStart(),
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [jTextPane.replaceSelection(String content)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#replaceSelection%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods can help you: Here is the link to javadoc [JTextPane.html#replaceSelection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#replaceSelection%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public void replaceSelection(String content) {
    replaceSelection(content, true);
}

private void replaceSelection(String content, boolean checkEditable)
```

In your example:

```
textArea.replaceSelection("");
```

will be enough,